# Defining regions with certain size using polygon layer as input in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, clustering, habitat-modeling

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.3 and have a project where I'm trying to define how may breeding habitats of a species that can fit into a specified area. I have a polygon layer with suitable habitat in this area and now I want to cluster all the suitable habitat polygons in this layer so it produces regions with 40 hectare suitable habitat (most polygons are smaller than that by themselves) but they do not need to be contacted to each other they can be spread out in an area up to 200 hectares.

I would like this to be optimized so as many territories as possible fit into this area. I'm thinking the region group tool can be used somehow if I convert the suitable habitat layer into raster?? Other methods are welcomed as well!

[image: map of my data frame with the suitable habitat layer in green and the boundaries of the area in red]

Comment: I am afraid this is NP problem - in order to find the optimal solution you would have to try all possible combinations. You could try to find suboptimal solution using some statistical methods (k-means clustering) or perhaps something like genetic algorithms could help. Either way, I don't think ArcGIS is suitable tool, you would be better off with R.

Comment: Thanks I'll try the K-means clustering tool and hope it works... unfortunately I do not have the time to learn R good enough to use that program but thanks for the help!